# How is The Median of three partitioning in Quick sort improve about 5% efficiency？

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

Recently I am learning the algorithm. The book is Mark Allen Weiss's "Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C".

When I read the Quick Sort Part, the book said the Median of Three Partitioning will improve the Quick Sort effciency for about 5%. Where is the 5% comes from? Could anybody give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397497/quick-sort-improvement-using-median-of-three-robert-sedwick) attributes it to Robert Sedgewick, but without an explanation.

On [this page](http://codeidol.com/java/java-algorithms/Quicksort/Median-of-Three-Partitioning/) you'll find a discussion of several sorting methods, including quicksort with and without median-of-three.

Below that is a table called 'empirical results' and it's not hard to spot the ~5% improvement. Given the vast complexity of analyzing over all possible inputs I think it's safe to say that Sedgewicks claim is based on measurements too.

Comment: But I still cannot get the point. Is 5% comes from the worst conditional  calculation?

Comment: No it comes from measuring comparisons on some (presumably) random data sets. You will always see: QuickSort is `O(n log n)` but for this discussion, QuickSort is `C * (n log n)` and we're talking about a 5% reduction in `C`.

Comment: I got it. So the result comes from practical running. Thanks a lot, you have done me a big favor~! : )